# HP Officejet Pro 8500 wireless printer

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

I replaced the black ink cartridge and still couldn't print because it now said replace the Yellow int cartridge.  I replaced the Yellow and then it wanted Magenta.  I replaced the Magenta and now it wants the blue and yellow.  The black was the only one that was empty.  I know that these other cartridges are not empty.  Why won't it print?

Answer (score 1):

Newer HP printers contain a sort of DRM in the cartridge that causes cartridges to have a lifespan, enforced by a chip in the cartridge. The printer may refuse to print simply because it deems that the cartridge is too old (6 months iirc), even if the cartridge has plenty of ink.

The company claims this is for print quality reasons.

(I've seen what old inkjet carts used infrequently spit out - it can be awful...but it means that when you want to print every six months, you need new carts & that's a waste.)

(Aside: this is why I use an old HP laser. It may eat power and spit ozone, but the cart runs out when there's no toner. Full stop.)